# Passing arguments to programs via Dash

Tags: unity, firefox, unity-dash, shortcuts

Note: I've found an answer myself while asking this question, **but is there a way to do it in regular Dash, that opens when you press SUPER - and not by using ALT+F2 (which seems like an unnecessary addition)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALT+F2` will allow you to run commands in the shell, so you can type e.g. `firefox ask.ubuntu.com` and that will open a new tab with the expected website.